# How to get all worklogs from JIRA/Tempo for a specific team and periode (Rest/API)?

Tags: json, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

Trying to get all worklogs from JIRA/Tempo for a specific team and periode (Rest/API). Using datacenter.

With this request it´s possible to get some informations, but missing team and specific informations about person, date etc.

```
/rest/tempo-timesheets/1/tempo-worklogs?jql=&currentUser=false&period=21&periodView=DATES&paginate=false&dateFrom=2020-05-01&dateTo=2025-05-10
```

Any ideas?